# Fail2ban filter apache-noscript does not match entries in apache log

Tags: apache, fail2ban

I'm using fail2ban 9.6.1 standard filters apache-common.conf and apache-noscript.conf.
However the apache-noscript does not match such entries in apache error_log:

```
[Thu Nov 23 07:32:25 2017] [error] [client 999.999.999.999] File does not exist: /path/to/requested/file

The _apache_error_client is:

_apache_error_client = \[\] \[(:?error|\S+:\S+)\]( \[pid \d+(:\S+ \d+)?\])? \[client <HOST>(:\d{1,5})?\]

The failregex in apache-noscript is:

failregex = ^%(_apache_error_client)s ((AH001(28|30): )?File does not exist|(AH01264: )?script not found or unable to stat): /\S*(php([45]|[.-]cgi)?|\.asp|\.exe|\.pl)(, referer: \S+)?\s*$
            ^%(_apache_error_client)s script '/\S*(php([45]|[.-]cgi)?|\.asp|\.exe|\.pl)\S*' not found or unable to stat(, referer: \S+)?\s*$

I guess I have either to modify the regex somehow or the log format of apache.
I tried removing the pid part from _apache_error_client but without success.
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I got an answer for this.
Adding a ? to /\S*(php([45]|[.-]cgi)?|.asp|.exe|.pl) fixes the problem.
So the working regex is

^%(_apache_error_client)s ((AH001(28|30): )?File does not exist|(AH01264: )?script not found or unable to stat): /\S*(php([45]|[.-]cgi)?|.asp|.exe|.pl)?(, referer: \S+)?\s*$

This can be marked as fixed.

Thanks